# html content extraction using htmlunit

Tags: java, extract, htmlunit

I have series of HTML files with the same structures.

Let take this example code.

```
>     <html>
>     <head>
>     <title>main page</title>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     <table><tr>
>     <td>content1</td>
>     </tr></table>
>     </body>
>     </html>
```

I want to extract the title tag content and td tag content.
How to do this using htmlunit?
I am new to htmlunit. Please help me.

Comment: Please read the documentation first and then ask any questions about specific problems you might have.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to test (that's what HTMLUnit helps with) or just extract.

Answer (score 1):

See this [instructive snippet](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) from the HTMLUnit page.

In there you first construct a client, then retrieve your page, finally ask for the title text (`page.getTitleText()`), or get the entire page as a HTML String (`page.asXml()`). You could then `assertContains` on that string.

There are plenty of other options, like retrieving elements by id.
Best see the examples for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

htmlunit is a testing system.  Not a DOM parser.

To parse HTML to a DOM use http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/ and use the [HtmlDocumentBuilder](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/apidocs/nu/validator/htmlparser/dom/HtmlDocumentBuilder.html) class.

Once you have a `Document` you can do `myDocument.getElementsByTagName("title")` to find the title element.

Comment: In fairness you can use HTMLUnit as an web scraper. I've seen it suggested on SO many times before.

Comment: @Joel Halbert, fair enough.  But in that case you're using HTMLUnit to both fetch and process content.   Doesn't HTMLUnit use NekoHTML to do the parsing?  If so, I would still say don't use HTMLUnit, since it's a (testing or scraping) framework, use an HTML parser like (nu.validator or tagsoup or neko) if you already have the content in hand.